# How to create an observable that defaults to a value (even if it never completes)

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is there a way to make an observable that will both start with an empty array and also default to an empty array if it does not pass the filter.

Here is what I'm working with

```
inactiveItems$: Observable<any[]> = combineLatest(this.store.select(fromAuth.getAuthState), this.showInactiveItems$).pipe(
  filter(([authState, showInactiveItems]: any) => authState?.roles?.isAgent === true && showInactiveItems === true),
  switchMap(([authState, showInactiveItems]) => this.db.collection('items', ref => ref.where('agentId', '==', authState.uid).where('active', '==', false)).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(
    catchError(err => of([]))
  )),
  startWith([])
);
```

A few explanations:

1) showInactiveItems is a boolean behavior subject

2) The authstate comes from an NgRx store

3) The observable from the switchMap is from AngularFire

I've tried using defaultIfEmpty operator but it only works when the observable completes or by adding like take(1) but with the observable from AngularFire, it needs to stay open so that if changes are made they will update in the app.

I've also tried messing around with the IIF creation operator but I couldn't figure how to make the observable run again when the condition changed.

Comment: I think what you need can be done with a BehaviourSubject observable

Comment: I'm currently using a behaviorSubject for the showInactiveItems boolean where the .next() is called whenever the user switches a switch on the ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` will stop the stream if the condition isn't matched. Instead, you should use `map` to return a value that determines whether `switchMap` runs or returns an empty array.

```js
inactiveItems$: Observable<any[]> = combineLatest(
  this.store.select(fromAuth.getAuthState), 
  this.showInactiveItems$
).pipe(
  map(([authState, showInactiveItems]: any) => {
    if (authState?.roles?.isAgent === true && showInactiveItems === true) {
      return authState.uid;
    }

    return null;
  }),
  switchMap(uid => this.getItems(uid))
);

private getItems(uid): Observable<any[]> {
  if (!uid) {
    return of([]);
  }

  return this.db.collection('items', ref => 
    ref.where('agentId', '==', uid)
       .where('active', '==', false)
    ).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(
      catchError(err => of([]))
    );
}
```

`map` returns the `uid` if the condition that you had in `filter` matches, otherwise returns `null`.

`switchMap` returns an empty array if `uid` is falsy, otherwise gets the items.